# What presentation software should I use for a five minute talk?

Tags: macos, software-rec, perl, slideshow, presentations

I am giving a lightning talk shortly and need to put together some slides.  It is a technical talk about Perl documentation.  I will be using a OS X machine to run the presentation software.

I would like something that is

- minimalistic
- easy to publish to the web
- simple to control (forward and back should do it, but hotkey access to individual slides would be nice)
- simple to create slides for (preferably purely text based and doesn't require much in the way of markup)
- will run when not connected to the net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [Vroom](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Vroom) and [Spork](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spork), both pretty minimal slide generators.

Answer (score 3):

How about S5? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/
(and here's the example show for a quick look http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/s5-intro.html)

It's entirely XHTML / CSS / JavaScript, and works in most web browsers (that I've tried anyway), so should be very easy to publish on the web.

You'll have to edit the XHTML to create slides; purely text based as you asked, but don't know if this meets your requirements RE minimal markup.

Comment: I have started playing with S5, specifically `Pod::S5` (http://search.cpan.org/dist/Pod-S5/S5.pm).  It looks fairly nice, but I none of the default themes are to my liking and I don't really want to spend the time hacking up a CSS file to make it look nice.  Right now it is my fall back position.

Comment: Damn... you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard  good things about [Prezi](http://prezi.com/) .

Comment: Good idea, but I am not guaranteed a network connection.  I have changed the question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: Note that you can download finished presentations for offline use: http://prezi.com/learn/portable-prezi/ There's even an offline editor (Prezi Desktop), but it needs a paid subscription.

Comment: @sleske Ah, good news, I saw that it was a web app and stopped looking.  I will have to give it another look.

Answer (score 2):

Google Docs - docs.google.com

You can share it easily.

Comment: Good idea, but I am not guaranteed a network connection.  I have changed the question to reflect this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

1. [NeoOffice](http://www.neooffice.org/) is free and opensource, works great on the Mac, and can export to PowerPoint, PDF, and various other formats (including, importantly, HTML for website viewing) for online and offline consumption. I would recommend this.
2. I've hear good things about [280 Slides](http://www.280slides.com/), which has a web interface that looks and uses like Apple Keynote, but of course runs on all platforms, and runs quickly. I seriously believe it supports downloading slides for offline use in Microsoft PowerPoint format, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I'd just go with a trial version of Powerpoint if you're limited on time.

There's a few alternatives here that you might be interested in:

http://www.socialtimes.com/2009/08/powerpoint-alternatives-best-online-presentation-software-for-business/?red=rb

In my opinion I'd use Sliderocket.